# TYPO3: FCE with FLUID but without an Extension

Tags: typo3

I have always used the extension Gridelements for my pages. Now I want to get away from using extensions for FCE. Is there a way with FLUID and Flexforms or similar to implement that as with gridelements?
For example, a bootstrap DIV "row" that contains a two-column element.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://usetypo3.com/custom-fsc-element.html. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a content element which contains 2 rows and which can have IRRE tt_content elements. I think there are enough examples how to make own content elements.

Additional for inline tt_content within tt_content records:

- in SQL make a couple extra columns for tt_content 2 for the content and 2 for the foreign key
- use a dataprocessor in typoscript to retrieve the IRRE tt_content records
- use overrideChildTca in TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php to set the colPos to 99 or so for the inline IRRE record fields (else the content elements will appear double on the page).
- set in the backend layout configuration of your main templates a fake column with colPos 99 to avoid TYPO3 9.5 warning that the inline content elements are not in a used column

Not sure if this is the best approach, but it will work. I guess you could also make it multidimensional by having inline in inline elements so you could make x columns. However I would just use Gridelements.